# How can I keep previous plot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Need to mark with circle on graph, but it doesn't overlap

[image]
[image]

```java
#set multiplot layout 2, 1 #  engage multiplot mode
#set multiplot
set font "arial,12" 

set autoscale

set datafile separator comma


#set offset 0,0,.5,.5
#set autoscale fix

set xtics out nomirror
set ytics out nomirror
unset border
set border 3
set format y "%0.04s %cV " 
set format x 


#set object circle at 5.2055,3430 size 25.5 lw 5 fc rgb "red"


$data <<EOD
3400,5.2055 
EOD

plot [3200:4400] "shurb/foo.csv"    u 1:2 w l lc rgb 'dark-green' title 'AP',\
    $data using 1:2 with circle lw 1 lc rgb 'red' notitle' ,
#unset multiplot
#set output
```

It is only drawing second one or first one, so I have to merge them on same plot.
How can I mark with circle or merge these two plots? Why I couldn't overlap them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I cannot fully follow what you are trying to do. How do you get two plot with a single plot command?
There is no need to use multiplot. Simply plot your datafile and your datablock `$data` with a single datapoint.

By the way, your commented `#set object circle at 5.2055,3430 size 25.5 lw 5 fc rgb "red"` has swapped x-, and y-coordinates. So, this circle object would not be visible on your plot.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.2)

```
### plot with circles
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Test separator comma
    plot [3200:4400] '+' u 1:(sin($0/6)*cos($0/20)/2.8*0.005+5.205) w table
unset table

$data <<EOD
3400, 5.2055
EOD

set datafile separator comma
set format y "%.4f mV"
set key noautotitle

plot [3200:4400] $Test u 1:2 w l lc "dark-green", \
      $data u 1:2 w circle lw 1 lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: My bad sorry. I want to use circle for specific area marking, instead of commonly used arrow marking, I'm using single plot for main canvas and other plots (marks) are just standing over on it. I need multiple marks, so I'm confused?

Comment: @maxemilian you need multiple marks? Do you mean multiple circles? Simply add more lines of xy-coordinates to your dataset `$data`.

Comment: Yeah I mean circles. Ok